# AngularJS page causes Chrome to use up huge tab memory in background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, momentjs

I have a, fairly simple, AngularJS page that simply uses a service to pull data from the backend and show it on screen using an ng-repeat.

During normal usage after 10mins the memory for the page stabilises at around 100mb.  If I switch tabs so that this page is no longer focused - it is in the background it will balloon in memory up until 1gb and then itll crash.

I am using `$interval` to refresh the data and I read recently that Chrome throttles intervals and timeouts when a page is in the background.  Shouldn't this prevent this from happening? Anything I can do? As a last resort I have considered switching to `requestAnimationFrame` as I know this won't get called when the page is in the background.

```
$interval($scope.update, $scope.refreshInterval);

//
//
//
$scope.update = function () {
    $scope.inError = false;

    scheduleAppAPIservice.getSchedules().then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.schedules = null;

            $scope.schedules = response.data;

            angular.forEach($scope.schedules, $scope.createNextExecutionLabel);
            angular.forEach($scope.schedules, $scope.createTrclass);
            angular.forEach($scope.tabs, $scope.assignSchedulesToTab);

            $scope.loading = false;
        },
        function () {
            $scope.inError = true;
            //console.log("failed getSchedules");
        });
};

//
//
//
$scope.createNextExecutionLabel = function (schedule) {
    schedule.nextExecutionDate = moment(schedule.NextExecution);
    schedule.endExecutionDate = moment(schedule.EndExecution);

    if (schedule.nextExecutionDate.year() > $scope.finishedCutoffYear) {
        schedule.nextExecutionLabel = "Never";
    }
    else if (schedule.IsCurrentlyExecuting) {
        schedule.nextExecutionLabel = "Running";

        if (!isNaN(schedule.CurrentProgress) && schedule.CurrentProgress != 0) {
            schedule.nextExecutionLabel += " (" + schedule.CurrentProgress + "%)";
        }
        else {
            schedule.nextExecutionLabel += "...";
        }
    }
    else if (schedule.nextExecutionDate < moment()) {
        schedule.nextExecutionLabel = "Overdue";
    }
    else {
        schedule.nextExecutionLabel = $filter('emRelativeTime')(schedule.nextExecutionDate);
    }
}

//
//
//
$scope.createTrclass = function (schedule) {
    var trclass = "system";

    if (schedule.IsDisabled) {
        trclass = "disabled";
    }
    else if (schedule.IsUserSchedule) {
        if (schedule.nextExecutionDate.year() > $scope.finishedCutoffYear && schedule.ExecuteOnEvent == 0)
            trclass = "finished";
        else
            trclass = "active";
    }

    schedule.trclass = trclass;
};

//
//
//
$scope.assignSchedulesToTab = function (tab) {
    tab.scheduleCount = $scope.schedules.filter(function (x) {
        return x.trclass == tab.label.toLowerCase();
    }).length;
};
```

Comment: Any resolution to that problem? i experience it as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any information about background tab throttling so, the theory in this answer may not be true.

`$interval` works, say, every 5 seconds.
But the successful promise inside the `$interval` may not be resolved in 5 seconds.

So if `scheduleAppAPIservice.getSchedules()` doesn't resolve in 5 seconds for some reason, an increased numbers of promises will consume memory on each `$interval` cycle.

You may cancel previous request when starting a new one on `$interval`, or you can use `$timeout` + manual invocation of the next request when promise completed to make sure there is nothing that consumes memory in an uncontrolled way.